# Ubuntu Pro ESM - Production

Tags: 16.04, esm, ubuntu-pro

I have some production servers running 16.04 LTS on AWS.

Is it recommended to enable Ubuntu Pro ESM on a production environment running version 16.04, or would it be advisable to wait before implementing this change?

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: Don't forget 16.04 LTS reached *end of standard support* back in 2021-April. If you've not enabled ESM at this stage, you've not been getting security fixes for well over a year now.  16.04 tells you it's the 2016-April release (2000 is added to *year* with *year.month* format used by Ubuntu), add 5 years to *year* and the EOSS is easily calculated; ie. 16+5 = 2021.April for EOSS or end of security fixes without ESM *enabled*.  If you used Ubuntu Pro media you may already have ESM enabled though.

Comment: ESM will increase the security of a 16.04 install. From AU Help: Questions you may ask: Services provided by Ubuntu and Canonical.

Comment: From AU help: avoid asking subjective questions. Like this one, where "recommended" or "advisable" is entirely a matter of opinion. Salespeople will say yes, extremely paranoid sysadmins will say no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking from **personal experience** in the workplace and at home, I would say **it depends on your infrastructure and the needs**.

At $DAYJOB, we have a number of critical servers providing critical components to business offerings to partners and such running on older 14.04 and 16.04 machines, and a handful of 12.04 ancient servers.  These systems are *temporarily* being covered by ESM to ensure security updates and patches, howeover this is **NOT** a replacement for fully updated systems.  Myself, the IT team, etc. have all been working to replace these outdated systems.  **While it's good to have security patches, ESM was designed with the intent of allowing 'some' leeway for patching, etc. for ongoing security support for a specific system, however it's only until you can find a replacement or migrate your systems off to newer versions of Ubuntu.**

It was never designed as an 'end all' solution for when a release goes End of Life - and never will.  It's designed as a stop-gap measure to permit you to run 'legacy' systems with (limited scope!) security coverage, while working to migrate your systems to updated OSes or software systems.

Therefore, the moment that your system reaches end of standard support (16.04 lost standard support in April of 2021 and ESM started then), you are in ESM support, and need to pay for Ubuntu Pro (previously branded Ubuntu Advantage for Infrastructure) to allow ESM entitlement **per server** in your environment (1 VM = 1 server).

Your primary goal regardless of Pro/ESM however is to **migrate your systems off of legacy unsupported software** and get them to a newer OS environment.

- Case in point: We just did that with four Python-driven API endpoints at $DAYJOB because we needed newer functionality unavailable in Python 3.6 (the version on the system in question that was EOL/EOSS) and was available in newer Python.  So we migrated it to a new 22.04 server.  The Python worked flawlessly and we were able to integrate newer Python 3.10+ functionality and modules that required Python 3.8+ to work, thus enhancing the in-house written software.

All in all, it will depend entirely on your organization, however ESM is a **limited backstop** - a band-aid to allow you to stay on the 'older' server software while working to migrate the workflow to newer Ubuntu systems or alternative software solutions (if working with software that's no longer available for newer releases for instance).

Comment: Very helpful answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

We are not the Ubuntu Pro sales team, not the Ubuntu Pro support team. Any recommendations we make are private opinions that may not match Canonical sales literature.

ESM does not begin until Standard Support ends (5 years). It does not matter if you enable (and begin paying for) ESM on day 1 or day 1825, the result will be the same.

- Other Ubuntu Pro services may, of course, be useful much earlier. But that's a conversation between you and the Ubuntu Pro sales team (whom we are not).
- Opinion: ESM is a limited stopgap, buying your organization a few extra years to migrate your enterprise workflow onto newer, fully-supported Ubuntu systems. Using ESM should be a temporary segment of a broader, organized, resourced migration project.